# Taking continuous inputs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, callback, bluetooth, runtime

I want to take data from bluetooth into Matlab every 10 to 15 seconds. I figured out a way to transfer data to Matlab via bluetooth. The problem I am facing is that I want Matlab to execute a set of commands after a time interval to take input from bluetooth. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a [TIMER OBJECT](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-38055.html), that you set to execute a function that collects and processes data every 10 to 15 seconds.